# java.awt.print.PrinterException: Printer is not accepting job

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am facing java.awt.print.PrinterException: Printer is not accepting job..Exception in my jsp page when sending documents to print dyanamically................

```
          String pdfFile = "D://Records.pdf";
          boolean silentPrint = false;
          String printerindx = "1";
          String password = "";

          PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

            if (pdfFile == null) {
                System.out.println("No PDF file available");
            }

            PDDocument document = null;

            try {
                document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
                if (document.isEncrypted()) {
                    document.decrypt(password);
                }
                PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

                if (printerindx != null) {
                    PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
                    for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
                        if (printService.getName().equals("HP LaserJet P1007") {
                            System.out.println("Printer found ....");
                            printJob.setPrintService(printService);
                            System.out.println(printService);
                        }
                    }
                }

                    document.print(printJob);

            } finally {
                if (document != null) {
                    document.close();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Printing Completed...");
```

whats going wrong ?

Comment: Well presumably the printer is not accepting the job... it's hard to know what to say beyond that. It's possible that the user that your JSP is running as (this is on the *server* side, of course) doesn't have access to the printer...

Answer (score 2):

According to this: [openjdk bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046007?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) it is an error in printing libraries, and you have some options:

1. Use different JRE where error is fixed.
2. Repeat printing until it will not throw, people with similar problem say it often worked on first repeat.
3. Use hack from here: [hack](https://community.oracle.com/message/5449533), see ForcedAcceptPrintService class

Answer (score 0):

**What Failed**

I've previously attempted the solution from Piro's third suggestion, but I received the same error that the succeeding poster (post #10) experienced.

**What Worked**

I performed the [bytecode hack](http://copy-con.blogspot.com/2009/12/printer-is-not-accepting-job.html), which overwrites the Win32PrintService getPrinterIsAcceptingJobs() method to always return a status of "ACCEPTING_JOBS."  This worked perfectly for my needs:  The printer is always seen as available and even if it's actually offline, print jobs are queued for whenever it comes back online.  The only thing I had to do differently was grab an older version of [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) (3.18) from GitHub since I'm compiling with Java 7.  Attempting to compile with the latest version (3.20) -- which is built with Java 8 -- gave me the following error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sun/print/Win32PrintService : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

For anyone else unfamiliar with the compilations necessary to create the PrintServiceFixer.jar, here are the steps I took:

1. **Copied javassist.jar to <JAVA_HOME>\jre\lib\ext**
2. **Compiled Win32PrintServiceFixer.java (from within <JAVA_HOME>\jre\lib)**

   ```
   javac -classpath .\rt.jar -bootclasspath ext\javassist.jar Win32PrintServiceFixer.java
   ```
3. **Created PrintServiceFixer.jar file:**

   ```
   java -cp .;.\ext\javassist.jar Win32PrintServiceFixer
   ```
4. **Copied PrintServiceFixer.jar from <JAVA_HOME>\jre\lib\target to the directory where I store my program's library/JAR files.**
5. **Ran my program**

   ```
   java -jar -Xbootclasspath/p:path\to\my\program's\libs\PrintServiceFixer.jar MyPrintingProgram.jar
   ```